# Proxy server to manage demo instances on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy

I manage a group of integration projects and for many we provide an Amazon instance with our product for development and/or demo purposes. In order to be economical with IT budgets, I wonder if there is a proxy software that can measure the traffic to those servers and start the instance on the first request and shut it down if there is no request for a set time (i.e. 60 min.)

Ideally the first request would trigger a page informing the user about the delay and keep autoloading until the instance has been up.
I'd also love to see usage statistics by IP, so I can measure the spread of users, how many different IPs, and the time they kept up the instance. But that is secondary.

Is there any such software/service out there? Preferably in FOSS?

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/) and [Custom CloudWatch Metrics](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2012/01/autoscaling-with-custom-metrics/) you can potentially use any data you want to decide how to Auto Scale. If you have other log sources or application level code, you won't need a proxy, just something to interpret that data, pass it to your CloudWatch metric and then the auto scaling will occur as needed.

Utilizing t1.micro, you can have one instance handling requests and scale out from there with your autoscale group. Pricing for 1 or 3 year [reserved instances costs extremely little](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#reserved). You need something to understand incoming volume, so having one instance would be required anyways. Using t1.micro, you operating costs are low and you can scale very granularly.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the suggestion,

It seems that AutoScaling assumes a min of one instance in each group. In my use case the min is 0 and the max is 1 instances running in a group.

It also seems that the CloudWatch Metrics need an instance running to measure the metric. That could work for finding out when to shut down, but not for when to startup.

I figure it'll need something like a proxy that receives the first request when the real target is down and then a proxy to measure when the last request came in and determine the timeout for shutdown.

Comment: Edited response to give some further detail that I think helps to alleviate that point.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting ... I had to learn the unusual formatting of stack exchange and did not master it before the 5 min edit timeout.

Comment: The proxy you speak of needs to run on something, so why not use your very cheap t1.micro instance to handle what you're speaking about and fit into the AWS model I am proposing which is a pretty standard solution for your issue.